# file upload limit in window 8

Tags: php, file-upload

i have a simple file upload code, the code works prety good on window xp and i test to upload the greater than 100kb, but in window 8 i use the same code and i am only be able to upload the maximum of 60kb file,
What is the reason, is there any bugs on window 8? or there is any other possible problem which cause to limit the uploading file.
i also try the code on another system which has window 8.1 installed but i find the same issue...
**Note:** it's not about the php.ini nor about the code, it's all about the logical error, so how can i solve it?
When i try to upload a file which size is greater then 60kb then the browser stuck on loading.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i clearly mention about that i am not able to upload a file which is greater then 60kb, and the default size of file upload in php.ini is 2MB, please read my question again...

Comment: What logical error are you speaking about? Win8 does not limit browser operations. Have you considered adding `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />` to the form and setting a value suitable to you? http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Use 'var_dump' and 'exit' to determine how far the script executes, that will narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the xammp version and hope it will solve the problem....

Comment: i just install the latest version of xammp and that's it.